# Dynamic drop down box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to create 3 drop down boxes dependent on each other. Each drop down box is getting its data from its own tables. There are 3 tables as shown:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the form:

```
<label for="tourtype">
  Tour Type 
</label>
<select id="tourtype" name="tourtype" required>

  <option value="" selected="selected">
    --Select--
  </option>
  <?php
       $sql=mysql_query("Select tour_type_id,tour_name from tour_type");
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       {
           $tour_type_id=$row['tour_type_id'];
           $name=$row['tour_name'];
           echo "<option value='$tour_type_id'>$name</option>";
       }
  ?>
</select>

<label>
  Country
</label>
<select id="country" name="country" class="country" required>
  <option value="" selected="selected">
    -- Select --
  </option>

</select>

<
<label>
  Destination
</label>
<select id="destination" name="destination" class="destination" required>

  <option value="" selected="selected">
    -- Select --
  </option>
</select>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tour_type').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "&id=" + id + "&get_countries=1",
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#country").html(html);
                }
            });
    });

    $('#country').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "&id=" + id + "&get_destination=1",
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#destination").html(html);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the ajax.php

```
<?php
include ('../config.php');
< ? php
if ($_REQUEST['get_countries']) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `countries`  where `tour_type_id`=" . $_REQUEST['id']);
    $countries = "";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $cid = $row['countries_id'];
        $name = $row['countries_name'];
        $countries.= "<option value='" . $cid . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }

    echo $countries;
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['get_destination']) {
    $destination = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `destination`  where `country_id`   =" . $_REQUEST['id'])
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $destination_id = $row['destination_id'];
        $name = $row['destination_name'];
        $destination.= "<option value='" . $destination_id . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }

    echo $destination;
}

?>
```

The problem is the 2nd and 3rd drop down boxes are not populating anything. Can anyone help me? For example if i select culture on the 1st drop down, the 2nd drop down should show Holland and Belgium. Then if i select Holland, the 3rd drop down should show Amsterdam.

Comment: Have you debugged the XMLHttpRequest? If not, install FireBug and watch the NET tab.

Comment: Also, your ajax.php will have a parse error. you should try accessing `ajax.php?id=1`. I also believe your `$.ajax` data is not formatted right (remove `&` from the ends of string)

Comment: Please consider tidying your code using one of the many [online formatters](http://phpbeautifier.com/) to make it more readable, this will help more users to be able to understand what your code is doing, and how best to answer your question.

Comment: are you sure your query is returning data and not just an empty string?

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner to coding and do not know my way around this forum. Can you simplify your explanation how to fix this issue please

Comment: @user1160022 what do you mean by empty string? Where in the code do you think the problem is?

Comment: this line: ``$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `countries`  where `tour_type_id`=".$_REQUEST['id']);`` are you sure it returns the country names and ids?

Comment: should the $_REQUEST['id'] be something else you reckon?

Comment: I really don't know where the problem is

Comment: btw HTML error: ``<<label> Destination </label>``

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31272/discussion-between-user1160022-and-munue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identifier in your Javascript is #tour_type when your id is #tourtype.

If the syntax is correct and your SQL results are correct too, it should work.

EDIT: some of your JS isn't right.

```
data: "&id=" + id + "&get_countries=1",
```

should be

```
data: {id: id, get_countries: 1},
```

You should also put a debug on your ajax call by adding

```
error: function () { alert("ajax failed"); }
```

after your success callback

full sources now:

```
$('#tourtype').change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url:"jurassicbase5/admin/ajax.php",
        data: {id: id, get_countries: 1},
        success: function(html){
        $("#country").empty();
        $("#country").append(html);
        },
        error: function () { alert("ajax failed"); }

    });
});

$('#country').change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "jurassicbase5/admin/ajax.php",
        data: {id: id, get_destination: 1},
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#destination").empty();
            $("#destination").append(html);
        },
        error: function () { alert("ajax failed"); }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok i have changed it to #tourtype. But the fault still the same

Comment: Do you use any kind of javascript/jquery dropdown ? Everytime I used one with a dynamic population like that it was what made the dropdown not populate. Try using the base selects of html if you don't.

Comment: Thanks Jay Zus and user1160022 for the huge help, this works now