# How to change a dropdown menu in php to change on select, and load next drop down options

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, onchange, onselect

Just like the title says, I have 3 drop down menus that I need to load on selection of the previous. It goes Country - State - City. So once a country is selected, I need the states menu to load all of the selections based on the country ID. And then once a state is selected, I need all of the cities to load for that state id. As of now, the countries load, but nothing happens when one of them is selected. So the other two dropdown menus only show "-- Select State--", and nothing else.

This is a common practice on sites to have an onchange event for dropdowns, however I have never coded something like this in PHP.

I did not create this PHP, so it is completely foreign to me. Here's what's in the file so far that's part of the dropdowns:

```
 <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label"> * Country : </label>
                <div class="controls">

                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('state_field',array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'state_field','value'=>'data[User][state_id]'));

                           echo $this->Form->input('city_field',array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'city_field','value'=>'data[User][citie_id]'));


                              $country=$this->Html->get_country();

                           echo $this->Form->input('countrie_id',array('type'=>'select','id'=>'country_down','class'=>'input-xlarge','options'=>$country,'empty'=>'-- Select Country --','label'=>false,'selected'=>$this->data['User']['countrie_id'])); ?>

                    <span class="help-block"> Select Your Country.</span>
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label"> * State : </label>
                <div class="controls" id="state_box">
                    <?php

                                if($this->data['User']['countrie_id']){
                                   $state=$this->Html->get_state($this->data['User']['countrie_id']);
                                } else{
                                   $state='';
                                }
                                   echo $this->Form->input('state_id',array('type'=>'select','id'=>'state_down','class'=>'input-xlarge','options'=>$state,'empty'=>'-- Select State --','label'=>false,'selected'=>$this->data['User']['state_id']));

                           ?>
                    <span class="help-block"> Select Your State.</span>
                </div>
        </div>

         <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label"> * City : </label>
                <div class="controls" id="city_box">
                    <?php
                    if($this->data['User']['state_id'])
                     {
                        $citi=$this->data['User']['state_id'];

                         $cities=$this->Html->get_city($this->data['User']['state_id']);

                      }else{
                                   $cities='';
                                }
                  echo $this->Form->input('citie_id',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$cities,'empty'=>'-- Select City --','class'=>'input-xlarge','label'=>false,'selected'=>$this->data['User']['citie_id']));
                    ?>
                    <span class="help-block"> Select Your City.</span>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: its more js than php as you want it load the next select with out reloading the page

Comment: onChange is not a php type event.  Generally a php script needs to process behind the scenes for a change.  You should look into AJAX to do what you want.

Comment: Is `$this` inside of a `class` method? You should use JavaScript, to do stuff on the Client Side. AJAX if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic drop down box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945019/dynamic-drop-down-box)